# Split View Master doesn't display after rotation to landscape - Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on an app using `SplitViewControllers` that I have written code to show an overlay when a bar button is pressed in portrait on an **iPad** and display side by side in landscape. The master has a `navigationController` with 3 levels of `tableViews` that update the `UI` in the detail view when selected. When I show the overlay in portrait, change my selection, dismiss the overlay, and then rotate back to landscape, my master is black with no data. When I rotate back to portrait, I receive the following error repeated several times:

`<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.`

This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

My detail viewController includes the following code:

```
    @IBAction func navBarButtonSplitViewPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
        if let split = self.splitViewController  {

            split.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay
        } // end if splitView

    } // end if portrait

}  // end navBarButtonSplitViewPressed

override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    if let split = self.splitViewController  {

        split.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.Automatic
    } // end if splitView

} // end willRotate
```